# Calculate columns on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas in python 3.7

```
data = {'call_put': ['C', 'P', 'P','C', 'P'],
        'strike': [280,260,275,280,285],
        'premium': [10,20,35,38,50]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(data) 
df['k']=df.groupby(['call_put']).cumcount() + 1
```

Output `df`:

```
    call_put    strike  premium k
0   C   280 10  1
1   P   260 20  1
2   P   275 35  2
3   C   280 38  2
4   P   285 50  3
```

I want to calculate two columns lower and upper. Calculations as follows

```
lower=strike-(total premium recd/kount cumm kount where call_put = "P" )
upper=strike+(total premium recd/kount cumm kount where call_put = "C" )
```

so expected output will be as follows

```
C   280 10 1    0                             290   (280+(10/1))
P   260 20 1   230     260-((10+20)/1)        290   (260+(10+20)/1)
P   275 35 2   242.50  275-((10+20+35)/2)     340   (275+(10+20+35)/1)
C   280 38 2   228.50  280-((10+20+35+38)/2)  331.5 (280+(10+20+35+38)/2)
P   285 50 3   234   285-((10+20+35+38+50)/3) 361.50(280+((10+20+35+38+50)/2))
```

I had tried following

```
data = {'call_put': ['C', 'P', 'P','C', 'P'],
        'strike': [280,260,275,280,285],
        'premium': [10,20,35,38,50]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['t']=df['premium'].cumsum()
df['k']=df.groupby(['call_put']).cumcount() + 1

df['l']=np.where(df.call_put == "P", df.strike-(df.t/df.k),df.strike-df.t)
df['u']=np.where(df.call_put == "C", df.strike+(df.t/df.k),df.strike+df.t)
```

It is giving me correct output, except for the first row

```
C 280 10 1 270 290
```

which should be

```
C 280 10 1 0 290
```

It depends where my value is "C" or "P"

Can you please help me with a more easy way?

Comment: Why should lower on the first row be 0?  280-(10/1) = 270. It would help if you could better explain the math you are actually trying to do. It also looks like you are misusing `np.where()`

Comment: Here at first row "P' kount is 0 so lower band should be 0

Comment: But it's `strike - `.. So it cannot be 0